# how i can get object with form:select in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-one

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String addVA(@ModelAttribute("va") VA va, BindingResult result){
    //BindingResult result

    System.out.print("VA = " +va);
    if(va.getIDVA() == 0){
        this.vaService.addVA(va);
    }else{
        this.vaService.updateVA(va);
    }
    return "redirect:/VA/";
}
```

**View:**

```
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="va">
        <table>
            <c:if test="${!empty va.name}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="IDVA">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="IDVA" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                    <form:hidden path="IDVA" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </c:if>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="name">
                        <spring:message text="Nom du version"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="name" />
                    <springForm:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="description">
                        <spring:message text="Description"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="description" />
                    <springForm:errors path="description" cssClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <form:label path="startDate">
                        <spring:message text="Date début"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <springForm:input path="startDate" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
                    <springForm:errors path="startDate" cssClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="endDate">
                        <spring:message text="Date fin"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <springForm:input path="endDate" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
                    <springForm:errors path="endDate" cssClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="projetMetiers">
                        <spring:message text="Projets"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:select multiple="true" path="projetMetiers" name="projetMetiers">
                          <form:options items="${projets}" itemValue="IDPM" itemLabel="name"/>
                    </form:select>
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Application</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>  
                        <form:select name="application" path="application">
                            <form:option value="-1"> --SELECT--</form:option>
                            <form:options items="${applications}" itemValue="IDAPP" itemLabel="name"></form:options>
                        </form:select>
                    </ul>  
                 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <c:if test="${!empty va.name}">
                        <input type="submit"
                            value="<spring:message text="Modifier"/>" />
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${empty va.name}">
                        <input type="submit"
                            value="<spring:message text="Ajouter"/>" />
                    </c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

The object application is null!